# Call a method or function from itself?

Tags: java, function

I am not able to understand how this will work as printAll is called from itself and calling in a for loop so how this function will reach at end. as when we call printAll from the for loop it will go and start the method again without ending it and then again comes to for loop and call printAll method without ending it and it will continuos do this, so can anyone explain how this funtions will work. because I am not able to understand this phenomenon.

```
private void printAll(Integer u, Integer d, List<Integer> savearray) {
        if (u.equals(d)) {
            this.saveinlist = new ArrayList<Integer>(savearray);
            return ;
        }

        for (Integer i : adjList[u]) {
                savearray.add(i);
                printAll(i, d, savearray);
                savearray.remove(i);

        }
    }
```

Comment: "this phenomenon" is called recursion

Comment: It only calls itself under particular conditions (which is why it doesn't loop forever). The part of the code that stops it from calling itself is called the "base case". A recursion tutorial will help explain the concepts further

Comment: now I searched for Recursion but not get a good understand. SO can you please in the code that i added above that what is happening in it.

Comment: No sorry, that's not really what this site is for. I know it's a confusing concept, but you will learn it if you search about it more. Trust me.

Comment: I thought developers will get each and every resolution over here

Comment: Where did you find this code snippet? You should ask the author what it's supposed to do. It's not very obvious to me what its purpose is (especially since the code snippet is incomplete).

Comment: ok. will try to get answer over there. thanks

Comment: No problem. Good luck

Comment: @B001ᛦ for telling me the method Process name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Recursive method. In a recursive method there are two parts.
1. Base condition
2. Recursive part

Base condition is which when we want to stop this recursive calling. 
In recursive part it called it self with some arguments. Because we have to use same set of codes to get our result.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/ go to this link if you know more about